# List of Names of Stock Exchanges

Tags: curated-data

executing the following code:

```
 sel = FinancialData["Exchanges"];
 csel = {#, FinancialData[#, "Name"]} & /@ sel // Dataset
```

results in a list attached below. It contains mainly names of enterprises, not names of stock exchanges. How can I retrieve the names of stock exchanges related to their symbols like BE, BG etc. in Mathematica?

(This list did not change trying it at different day times)

Thanks in advance, Opal

[image]